# I'm having trouble installing virtualbox 5.1 via the CLI .. my software install is not installing the Deb package

Tags: apt, virtualbox

I tried to follow another question that had the same problem but the command:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential virtualbox-5.1 dkms
returns E: Package 'virtualbox-5.1' has no installation candidate
Can anyone help me with this?
```

I had this all working then I rebooted and my virtualbox installation had vanished .... which I'm sure is a whole another can of worms. I just want Virtualbox installed. Please help.

Just FYI I try and install this through Ubuntu Software (after downloading 5.1) and the Install button goes gray for about two seconds then in my launcher an icon comes up and says "waiting to install"

A solution to either of these problems would suffice .. help.

Comment: Did these `linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential dkms` install when you tried? There are two options to installing virtualbox 1) from ubuntu repos, 2) from `deb` file downloaded from oracle site. The issue your having is that the version you seek is too recent to be found in the official repos. So that won't fly

Comment: No ... it returned .... Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package virtualbox-5.1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'virtualbox-5.1' has no installation candidate
I downloaded the deb from oracle site, when I try and install it via the Software center it installs for 2 secs then puts an icon on my launcher says waiting to install and never does anything ... is there another way to do this?

Comment: By return you mean it didn't install? Run `which virtualbox`

Comment: i did not install ... at least I dont think it did .. the message I received and posted did not look very promising

Comment: ok, now run this from terminal. First change into the folder with that `deb` file then run `sudo dpkg -i <name_of_virtualbox_file>.deb`

Comment: A MILLION thank you's for the expert and fast answers ... it looks like it is working now.!!

Comment: Great glad I could help!

Answer (score -1):

Install `gdebi`:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

Then download the `.deb` file and run:

```
gdebi your_file.deb
```

(First `cd` to where your file is.)